# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in ansible output

Tags: python, docker, ssl, ansible

I have set up an ansible tower using the following docker image

```
ybalt/ansible-tower:latest
```

After setting up I have upgraded the applications inside the container by

```
apt-get upgrade
```

After that following are the versions inside my conatiner

```
ansible 2.7.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Jul 18 2016, 15:02:52) [GCC 4.8.4]
```

Then when I execute a script that uses the mail module in ansible the following error shown in the ansible tower output

```
fatal: [Server]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1549369654.27-211111564926363/AnsiballZ_mail.py\", line 113, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1549369654.27-211111564926363/AnsiballZ_mail.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1549369654.27-211111564926363/AnsiballZ_mail.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_mail_payload_bQeVQh/__main__.py\", line 381, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_mail_payload_bQeVQh/__main__.py\", line 330, in main\r\nTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdo…
```

I have developed a seperate palybook with email configurations inorder to refer from an any playbook. So the following is the variables that I have defined in the playbook

```
email_host: "smtp.sendgrid.net"
email_port: 587
email_username: "username"
email_password: "password"
email_to: "admin@example.com"
email_cc:
email_subject: "test"
email_body:
email_subtype: "html"
email_secure: "try"
email_from: "noreply@example.com ( Ansible Tower )"
email_bcc:
email_attach:
```

Following is the way how i refer to the above email playbook from my other playbooks

```
- name: Email body on failure
  set_fact:
    email_body="Hi {{ tower_user_name }}, <br><br> Status - Failed
                                                                  <br> Issue - Build path or given build name doesn't exist
                                                                  <br> Suggested Solution - Check the validity of the build path or the build name.
                                                                  <br><br> Thank You"

- name: Sending an email
  include_role:
    name: email
    tasks_from: main.yml
  when: path_build_location.stat.exists == False
```

But when that section triggers and when a second play book tries to send an email. I get the above error. Variables in my ansible config file are fully commented out and all are overidden by the ansible tower variables.  All the configurations are rechecked and are according to the ansible documentation. I even can sent the notifications via the ansible tower but not through the mail module in ansible. But I expected to sent the mail automatically by the ansible script. But that didn't happen..

Comment: `Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.` is a normal output. Fix `mail` module execution.

Comment: What do u mean by fix the mail module execution ? Is there an apparent mail module issue in the above configurations.. I'm bit new to ansible.. it would be great if you can elaborate the issue bit. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your actual error is in module_stdout `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. must be referring to a variable which is null or unknown variable type.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error is in module_stdout `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. must be referring to a variable which is null or unknown variable type.